# How to load video from local file URL without MediaStream

Tags: reactjs, react-player

What's the way play local videos? This option doesn't work:

```
const url = '/localVideo.mp4';

<ReactPlayer url={url} width="100%"
             height="100%"
             controls={true} />
```

I get the error that src attribute is empty:

> MediaError {code: 4, message: 'MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Empty src
> attribute'}

The url is a correct sting, works fine with native `<video` element.

I checked the sources for the library, and it seems like the `MediaStream` [is required](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/blob/9775bb755af195e6f7e8bacfed436fcefb135354/src/players/FilePlayer.js#L214):

```
   if (isMediaStream(url)) {
      try {
        this.player.srcObject = url
      } catch (e) {
        this.player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(url)
      }
```

MDN says it's [no longer required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#using_object_urls_for_media_streams). It should work with a string.:

> In older versions of the Media Source specification, attaching a
> stream to a element required creating an object URL for the
> MediaStream. This is no longer necessary, and browsers are removing
> support for doing this.

Comment: thanks, tried like that `<ReactPlayer url={[myVideo]}`, still the same error, for some reason the library adds empty `src` attribute to the `video` tag which causes the error, even thought there's a nested `<source src="...">` with correct url when passing url as an array

Comment: Weird, works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-qjzrkx?file=/index.js

Comment: yeah, it works for me too for URLs on the web, doesn't work for local files

Comment: And you're sure the URL is correct? If you do `fetch(url).then(resp => console.log(resp.url))` and navigate to the logged URL you see your video?

Comment: @Kaiido, yeah, I can even see the video if put into `<video url=""` native control or using Chrome Devtool `open in` functionality